# Low cost airlines search engine?

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, low-cost-carriers, flight-search-engines

With wheretowhen.com dying a few years ago and, now, airninja.com having become a regular (non-budget) flight search engine, is there any website left which lists the routes of budget airlines and makes them easily searchable?

Note that something like hipmunk (though excellent) isn't applicable, as most low cost airlines don't show up on hipmunk (nor on most other flight search engines).

Comment: Hmm, for example http://www.itasoftware.com/ also lists budget airlines. Why are you looking for a search engine only for budget airlines?

Comment: [momondo.com](www.momondo.com) does it too. By the way, the reason why it is not available is that low-cost airlines do not want to make it available.

Comment: @Vince: I know. both websites I mentioned didn't allow you to actually search for flights, but allowed you to search for routes. But, indeed, momondo does appear to be listing budget airlines too! huh! Make it an answer, quick! :)

Comment: @Rofl: Google's public front for itasoftware doesn't do Europe. Because, typically, flight search engines don't include budget airlines, I like to have one place where I can see at least all the routes for all budget airlines. It seems momondo is helpful enough, though.

Comment: Note that usually Ryanair does not show up in any of these search engines. You will have to look up directly in their website.

Comment: The extremely major problem with Ryan Air is that if you book and pay for a flight with them, then you will have to fly with them (or try to) (or may find yourself choosing to do so).

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38381/how-do-i-search-for-connecting-point-to-point-flights

Comment: Not sure I agree with the statements about Hipmunk.  Hipmunk just told me I could fly TPE-PUS for US$ 85 on Kingfisher.  Kingfisher shut down several years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So apparently [momondo.com](http://www.momondo.com), unlike other websites, allows you to book budget flights.

Glad it helps!

note: low cost airlines do not make their flights available for booking in traditional tools so tools like momondo might not work forever, because it is based on web-scraping or such techniques (for example if a low-cost airline changes its website it might break)

Comment: It does list several of the low cost airlines, which is cool. But I did realise that airninja had a particular value not found anywhere else, to my knowledge: It allowed you to select a country of departure, which would then show you all countries to where you could fly using budget airlines alone, independent of actual departure city, destination city or date.

Answer (score 12):

I use [trabber.com](http://trabber.com) or [skyscanner.com](http://skyscanner.com) it's not only for low-budget airlines but it finds the cheapest prices (at least here in Europe)

Answer (score 8):

I find [adioso.com](http://adioso.com) interesting. I've not booked using it so far but have used it to check costings and flights. It provides rapid and easy access to information that others don't.

It has a (somewhat) natural language search engine (or a more conventional one can be used) and provides graphs of prices across date ranges. It highlights the cheapest flight in the date range selected both graphically and numerically. In the NZ-Asia region JetStar seems to feature a lot.

You can ask it questions like "AKL to CAN early October". I just had a look and they have made the search somewhat more formal with eg from and to boxes, but it is still quick and easy to use.

---

Probably not of interest, but within China I have made extensive use of http://ticket.9588.com/ with good results. They list all available internal airlines and allow you to see discount rates and number of seats at that rate for all future dates. Discounts of up to 70% AFAIR are available in some cases for early enough bookings.

Answer (score 7):

[Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com) even shows connections composed of flight segments by several low cost providers. This is a home-brew solution, which they name *Multi-part bookings*. Though impressive, it is risky: If the first flight is delayed (pictured: [Ryanair](http://www.ryanair.com/)) then you are not guaranteed to get the connecting flight (pictured: [germanwings](http://www.germanwings.com/)).
[image: Multi-part booking]

Answer (score 5):

[Mobissimo](http://www.mobissimo.com/search_airfare.php) is a travel search engine that allows consumers to compare prices on cheap flights alongside hotels, and car rentals. It aggregates the results from over 180 online travel agencies, consolidators, and ticket vendors to show a side-by-side comparison of the best deals found on the web. It then redirects the visitor to the site with the best rates.

Other cheap flight search engines I am aware of include:

http://www.airfaresflights.co.uk/

http://www.dohop.com/

http://www.fly.com/uk/Default.aspx

http://www.jumblefly.com/

http://www.kayak.co.uk/

http://www.dealchecker.co.uk/

http://www.travelsupermarket.com/c/cheap-flights/

Comment: Mobissimo says nobody goes TPE to PUS on 31 Jan.  I already know of three airlines that do it for under US$ 200.  And when I tried to change the destination to ICN, it crashed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Cheap flights finder](http://www.cheapflightsfinder.com)? They define themselves as a meta-meta search engine, because they compare across the comparison sites. They include skyscanner, momondo and some 800 sources for cheap flights.

I'm not aware of anything more all-encompassing than this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Don't like it too much, though. It appears to effectively just be a browser tool, opening up separate windows for each search engine.

Comment: +1 for meta-meta search engine. One day someone just had to do this. Usefulness is questionable, though.

Answer (score 2):

Low Cost Airlines saves money by only allowing you to book on their sites; that's one of the ways they manage to give you low fares.

With that said try the following to see if they show the airlines you want:

http://www.skyscanner.com
and
http://www.opodo.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

try this search engine:

http://www.airtickets.aero

Results including European low cost airlines only

Comment: Interesting. But, I tried a few searches and the returned prices were quite inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

www.azuon.com specifically searches and connect low cost airlines. The program found many connections for me, esp. within Europe, that are way cheaper than what is available online with traditional search engines such as skyscanner or momondo.

Comment: azuon downloads a Windows installer.  I wouldn't touch that even if I had Windows!

Comment: Well, times change, people change, and even tools change.  I have used Azuon a lot in the past twelve months on Mac for flights North America to and from Europe and South America. But now I'm trying to go USA to Taiwan to So. Korea to USA.  Azuon can't find ANY flights over a month-long period USA to Taiwan nor So. Korea to USA.