# How do I search for connecting point-to-point flights?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, airlines, flight-search-engines

There are often situations where buying two separate one-way tickets from A to C via B is cheaper than buying a normal multi-leg ticket. This can be especially useful with airlines such as Ryanair, which specifically avoids selling multi-leg tickets.

Is there a search engine which allows one to search for such flights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excerpt from [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62685/32134) and [this answer of mine.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62626/32134) See also [this question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67122/32134) even though it is about to be marked duplicate.

[azair](http://www.azair.com/) has very powerful search options (see the advanced options), including choice of return and departure day, length of stay, period within which the trip should happen and a range of departure and arrival airports. Exactly as you ask they look for connections on separate tickets [(consider also this Q&A)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66408/can-i-fly-via-a-third-city-on-a-second-ticket), even on different (low-cost) airlines.

[image]

[Skypicker](https://en.skypicker.com/) does the same and let's you circle departure/destination in on a map, has date range and also some kind of "promise" to help you if you miss a non-guaranteed connection.

Finally be aware of [pro's and con's of flying on separate tickets.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66408/can-i-fly-via-a-third-city-on-a-second-ticket)

Comment: This site was clearly not developed for the average flyer. Just look at that UI.

Comment: Azair is exactly what I was originally looking for!

Comment: @BurhanKhalid not every flyer is an average one! There should be something for everyone! There are already plenty websites for average flyer like Google Flights and Skyscanner and it's really refreshing to see the websites in this answer that give you more control and options.

Answer (score 3):

Our website at http://www.skyscanner.net provides this functionality. You can do a flight search and choose "Airline combinations" in the results page filter. This lets you see results where several ticket bookings are required, also known as "non-protected transfers". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Ryanair flights, you may try [Ryalive](http://www.ryalive.com/en/).

Marking this as community wiki because  originally https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1319/ilakast posted it in one of the duplicates.